# Perl gives: "Use of uninitialized value $k in addition (+) at ./one.pl line 98"

Tags: perl

Perl gives me this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $k in addition (+) at ./one.pl line 98, <FILE2> line 2000.
```

The code-snipped is the following:

```
sub calcMu
{
  my $sum = 0;
  my $lengStrs = length($_[0]);
  my $lengArray = @_;
  my $k = 0;
  my @result = makeDistMatMu(@_);

  for $k (@result) {$sum += $k;}

  $sum/($lengStrs * ($lengArray*($lengArray-1)/2));
}
```

In @result we have for example (0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1)

Comment: You say `@result` contains some numbers, but this warning says it contains an undefined value. It looks like that comes from the `makeDistMatMu` function that you call, and it is likely the error comes from that function, and not this one. Hiding this warning might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@result` contains `undef` values.  Look in `makeDistMatMu` to see how they could get there.

If you just want to treat these values as 0, you can change the loop which calculates `$sum` to

```
for $k (@result) {$sum += $k || 0;}
```

Oh, and you can remove the `$k = 0` line.  It doesn't have any effect, since the loop overwrites `$k` with values from `@result`.

Comment: IMHO `for my $k (@result)` could be used instead of define `$k` outside the for-loop.

Comment: Hiding the error might not be a great idea, since the undefined values might be a problem with the other function `makeDistMatMu`. The sample input he gives looks like a simple list of numbers, nothing undefined.

Comment: @TLP: We don't know enough about the OP's use case to say whether `undef` is an error or if it should be treated as 0, hence "If you just want to treat these values as 0...".

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid warnings by skipping undefined values in @result,

```
for my $k (@result) {
  next if not defined $k;

  $sum += $k;
}
```

or by short circuiting `$k` and `0` using `//` operator

```
for my $k (@result) {

  $sum += $k // 0;

  # same as:
  # $sum += defined $k ? $k : 0;
}
```